# Password_hash error 500 with PHP 5.6.8

Tags: php, passwords, bcrypt, password-hash

I am trying to use the password_hash function, but my server returns a 500 error.
I am using the PHP 5.6.8 version, so it should be compatible.

This is my code:

```
private static $options = array('cost' => 11);
public static function hash($password) {
        // i.e. '123'
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
    }
```

Comment: How do you know there problem is in there?

Comment: Have you run  a lint check on the script to see if it flags up any syntax errors?

Comment: Yes, It dont detect any syntax errors

Comment: If I use I change password_hash() to crypt(), it works.